# Facebook App Create , and submission for review

Tags: facebook

I have created an app in facebook , that required user read_stream, publish_action permissions.

What should i write in review part of facebook app submission , so they accept those permission .

because they want to test . but how would i allow them to test for my website ?

Comment: You should write what you do with those permissions. And you should make it possible for the reviewer to test it.

You should probably also read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#reference-extended-read which say the following about read_stream: "Provides access to all the posts in the person's news feed. This permission is reserved for apps that replicate the Facebook client on platforms that don’t have a native client. It may only be used to provide people with access to this content. It may take up to 14 days for your app to be reviewed."

Comment: As i wrote this app for my website only not for canvas . how the reviewer can test .I have included the images , what my website would do , if a user login . what else i should write !

Comment: Why can't the reviewer test your site?

Comment: how could i allow test-account that reviewer will used , as admin . so they can see , what we can as admin .